# Why ROS Publisher doesn't work without a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, ros

```
def talker(self):        
        rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            hello_str = "I AM IRON MAN "
            self.pub.publish(hello_str[2:4])
            self.pub.publish(hello_str[5:9])
            self.pub.publish(hello_str[10:13])
            rate.sleep()
```

I tried the above code and successfully heard by the subscriber. But when I try the code below, subscriber doesn't get the published message. I was wondering why the code above works and below doesn't?

```
def talker(self):        
        rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        hello_str = "I AM IRON MAN "
        self.pub.publish(hello_str[2:4])
        self.pub.publish(hello_str[5:9])
        self.pub.publish(hello_str[10:13])
        rate.sleep()
```

Comment: Could you put on your complete code? In below code, if you call `talker()` it should be published three times.

Answer (score 1):

Publish doesn't need a loop to work.

**This function send only one message.**

**Test**  : Launch your subscriber, then launch your publisher. You should see one set of data.

---

If you don't finish your script with an infinite loop. Your node will be done and closed.

We use sleep and publish inside an infinite loop to publish data at a specific rate.

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really needs a loop.

You can call spinOnce and let it keep running.

Then at each subscriber call back, publish the subscriber content.

Whenever there is a call back, some call back will be activated. thus publisher will also work.

This will also work. Take note, for time depended control singal or running PiD or nonlinear controller, it best to place to a time loop.

Those are a typical example of Fix time pooling and Interrupt service routing.

For details, you can try to find some Chinese middle school textbook. its all up there

[image]